# how to create a table with the text of columns centered and justified?

Tags: tables

I'm a new with Latex, I'm trying to create my Thesis . But I'm stuck in how to create a table. 
I have tried to use [this link](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/#) which make latex tables online. but I didn't succeed to create my table with it .

I have this table :

[image]

could you help me please ?

Comment: Well, this is a screenshot, but does not reveal, what you did. Please post a compilable document. You need the `c` columntype and `\multicolumn` command (occasionally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with `tabularx` and `multirow`. Note the first argument of `\multirow` is not the number of rows, but the number of *lines*, thus it really depends on the real contents of the rows, and requires an optional argument for a small correction. I also gave some vertical padding to the rows, setting `\arraystretch` to a value > 1.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{array, tabularx, multirow}%
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\hsize=.34\hsize\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\hsize=.66\hsize\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
  \begin{tabularx}{0.8\linewidth}{|Y|Y|Z|Z|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\bfseries Fonction} & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Degré  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{8}{\hsize}[1.2ex]{\centering Some labels (centred)} & A & I want this text to  be   justified & \multirow{8}{\hsize}[1.2ex] {\centering Some description (I want it to be centred)}
    \\
    \cline{2-3}
                                                                  & B & I want this text to  be   justified &                                                                                     \\
    \cline{2-3}
                                                                  & C & I want this text to  be  justified  &                                                                                     \\
    \cline{2-3}
                                                                  & D & I want this text to  be  justified  &                                                                                     \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Some labels} &  I want this text to  be  justified  & Some labels \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry but is there a way to make this table span into two pages . ( it's long with my data ) ?

Comment: Yes: load `ltablex` instead of `tabularx`. It combines the functionalities of `tabularx`  and `longtable` (a caption must be set in the way longtable does).

Comment: thanks for your reply .. I have changed to `ltablex` and added this package `\usepackage{ltablex}  ` but i got errors .. do `table` allow this separation into 2 pages .?

Comment: I think not. Forr longtable, one doesn't use it. *A priori*, when you split a table across pages, you don't want it to float.  So replace `table` with `center` (and delete `\centering`): If you need a cation, use `\captionof[table]{…}`.

Comment: thank you for your directions :) 
I have used `tabularx` and changed `begin{center}` as you have suggested . because `ltablex` generates errors 
it works now :)

Comment: Do  you mean you used the `ltablex` environment? There is no such environment. The ltablex *package* is loaded to let the `tabularx ` environment break across pages.

Comment: oh ok .. I'm new with this .. I misunderstood you !